# Selecting if count for different value is 1 or more

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table data,

```
Number              Code
   1                 430
   1                 430
   2                 430
   2                 430
   3                 420
   3                 340
   3                 430
   1                 420
```

Given the above data, I am trying to get records which have different code exist on them to make it clear following is the output I am expecting.

```
Number              Code
  1                 430
  1                 420
  3                 420
  3                 340
  3                 430
```

If you see I am only selecting a number where different code exists if the number doesn't have different code on them I don't want to select that number.

I have tried with `group by` with `having` and then filtering out the matching codes but I am still not able to figure it out and messing with my output. I can't add `having count(*) > 1` because same number can have multiple rows with same code.

Any help or pointers would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to distinctly count the code grouped by Number, and distinctly show in the main query :

```
WITH t AS
(
SELECT Number
  FROM tab
 GROUP BY Number 
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Code) > 1 )
SELECT DISTINCT t2.*
  FROM tab t2
  JOIN t
    ON t2.Number = t.Number
 ORDER BY t2.Number
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b69d810df84e45de0c6b8da313830260)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You can try this below logic with sub query-

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM your_table
WHERE num IN
(
    SELECT num
    FROM your_table
    group by Num
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Code) > 1
)
```